# Remove all the spaces between `;` and `CRLF`

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ v8.4.6.

I want to replace all the spaces after `;` at the end of the line on Windows.

I have used this:

`;\s{1,}[r\n]+`

And it finds correctly, but when I try to replace, removing all the spaces between `;` and CRLF, it doesn't do anything.

How can remove all the spaces between `;` and `CRLF`?

This is what I've tried:

[image]

Comment: Try `;\K\h+(?=\R)` and replace with an empty string or `;\K\h+$` if the newline is not mandatory

Comment: `[r\n]` matches a newline char or the literal `r` character.

Comment: Is `CRLF` a stand in for "end of line" or do you have mixed CR, LF, CRLF line endings and want to specifically match the CRLF ones only?

Comment: @knittl No, is the thing that appears at the bottom of the program: Windows (CR LF).

Comment: Could you give sample text **and** expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
find What: ;\s+$
Replace:   ;
```

Comment: works for me to. But this answer is already given by knittl.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *"remove all the spaces between ; and CRLF"* and a newline is mandatory, you could match `;` followed by forgetting what is matched so far with `\K`

Then match one or more horizontal whitespace characters with `\h+` and assert any unicode newline sequence with `\R`.

**Note** that `\s` also matches a newline.

```
;\K\h+(?=\R)
```

or

```
;\K\h+(?=\r\n)
```

If you only want to match horizontal whitespace characters until the end of the string to remove:

```
;\K\h+$
```

[image]

After the replacement:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to match all semicolons followed by spaces at the end of line, the replace it with the literal semicolon only:

- Search: `;\s+$` or if you are only interested in spaces (ignoring tabs), then `; +$`
- Replace: `;`

Comment: I'm not sure if I have understood your answer. I only want to remove all the spaces and keep the ; and the newline.

Comment: @VansFannel the `$` anchor will not be replaced; it only anchors the regex at the end of line. And if replacing `;    ` with `;` is equivalent to dropping all the spaces.