# Remove the spaces before ; and after ; without removing the new line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ v8.4.6.

I want to replace all the spaces after and before `;`. For example, given this line:

`H;53; ;00 00 35.37;-29 15 48.2;10.96; ;H;000.14739023;-2.926.338.247; ;  -1.76;   11.94;  -12.96;  2.18;  1.03;  2.45;  3.15;  1.27; 0.03;-0.07; 0.07; 0.27; 0.05; 0.08;-0.10;-0.32; 0.11;-0.22;0; 1.19;53;      ;     ;      ;     ; ;      ;     ; ;    ;    ;T; ;111.006;0.0041;0.041;152; ;11.03;11.17;       ; ; ; ;          ; ;  ;1; ; ; ;  ;   ;       ;     ;     ;    ; ;G; ;      ;          ;C-29 18916;          ;0.72;            ;`

I want to get this:

```
H;53;;00 00 35.37;-29 15 48.2;10.96;;H;000.14739023;-2.926.338.247;;-1.76;11.94;-12.96;2.18;1.03;2.45;3.15;  1.27; 0.03;-0.07; 0.07; 0.27; 0.05; 0.08;-0.10;-0.32; 0.11;-0.22;0; 1.19;53;;;;;;;;;;;T;;111.006;0.0041;0.041;152; ;11.03;11.17;;;;;;;;1;;;;;;;;;;;G;;;;C-29 18916;;0.72;;
```

On my previous question [Remove all the spaces between `;` and `CRLF`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76256597/remove-all-the-spaces-between-and-crlf), I got how to remove that spaces.

Now I have tried this to remove the space after `;`, but it also remove the new line at the end of the line:

[image]

If I have this:

`;  C-29 18916 ;`

I want to get this:

`;C-29 18916;`

WITHOUT REMOVING THE NEW LINE CHARACTER.

How can I do that without removing the new line there is something like this `;\n`?

Comment: use `" *; *"` (without quotes)as seach string.`\s` will find all sorts of whitespaces (space, tab, newline ...). If you explicitly only search for `" "` (ie the space character) it won't replace any other whitespaces

Comment: Match one or more space followed by a colon or match one or more space preceded by a colon " +(?=;)|(?<=;) +" and just remove that space(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace all spaces before and after `;`, match on
 `*; *`

- `*` - (a space followed by `*`) matches on zero or more spaces
- `;` - a literal `;`
- `*` - zero or more spaces

and substitute with `;`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/REhfZp/1)

Comment: Perhaps you should also use that `para nueva linea` option. I don't know the language or notepad++ but it's worth a try.

Comment: In RegExs in Notepad++, `\s` matches newline characters. One can use `\h` to match horizontal whitespace and `\v` to match vertical whitespace.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Ok, cool. Is that so even with the `para nueva linea` option checked? :-) It sounded like it could make a difference.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Since I don't know what `para nueva linea` actually does, I replaced `\s` with space which should do what OP asked for.

Comment: Comparing to my English version of Notepad++, the "para nueva linea" is in the same place as mine says ". matches newline" (against a tick-box). The OP appears to be from Spain and Google translate for "para nueva linea" gives "for new line".

Comment: @AdrianHHH Hmm, yeah, perhaps it doesn't do what I hoped for. Did you try it out to see if it makes a difference? I'll probably stick with the ` *; *` solution in my answer anyway. That should at least do what OP asked for with or without that option checked.

Comment: "para nueva línea" means "for new line".

Answer (score 2):

Use `h*;\h*` and replace with `;`

`\h*` stands for 0 or more horizontal spaces.